# Base Internationalization does now work in Ionic iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, localization, internationalization

I have added iOS platform with ionic.
New XCode iOS projects comes with base internationalization but ionic iOS project (Ionic CLI v1.7.16) is not coming with base internationalization:
[image: no localization]

When I want to add base localization, I cannot be successfull because there is no localization resource:

[image: no localization resource]

In fact, there is MainViewController.xib in classes folder but no effect.

How can I use base internationalization with ionic iOS project?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to go to your storyboard file, open the bar on the right side, and go to Show the File Inspector, the furthest tab to the left. Then, scroll down and click localize. After this, when you check Use Base Localization, you should see the storyboard appear.